# NativeScript firebase plugin

Tags: firebase, nativescript, nativescript-firebase

I'm developing a mobile app using nativeScript.

When i'm trying to use nativeScript firebase plugin, nativeScript sidekick app gives the following error:

> Plugin nativescript-plugin-firebase is not included in preview app on device 7D3433B1-7016-41A1-AAF7-66B7B163BB17 and will not work.

I tried to run it on preview app, 
can anyone help with this.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error log confirms, Preview app only works with limited set of plugins. Plugins those do not require native dependencies to be more precise. Hence Firebase plugin can't be used with Preview app, you will actually have to build the project in your local machine if you want to try this plugin.

Comment: Manoj thanks for your feedback,i have developed it my local pc,I can get it now only default plugins can works with preview  app, can anyone suggest me a good ios emulator, hence i'm new to mobile development??

Comment: You are using a Mac or Windows?

Comment: i'm using Windows machine

Comment: NativeScript CLI & Sidekick support cloud build that would help you build your app from a Windows machine, basically the source code is uploaded to a remote machine and built there, then you could directly run the package on your local iOS device. But unfortunately it is not possible to run the iOS Simulator on Windows at all, which is a limitation from Apple.

Comment: I have face that problem,I thought that it was a problem of the emulator, now I get it,as you above mentioned can I run this app on my iPhone 5s by connect it to my local pc??

Comment: Yes, you can but you have to opt for Cloud Build on Windows.